# Given α and β are complex numbers, what is an alternate form of writing |α + β|²?

Tags: complex-numbers

I was doing a question on complex numbers (see the linked image) and I'm quite unsure why you can say that $|α + β|² = (α + β)(\overline{\alpha} + \overline{\beta})$, and similarly why $|α - β|² = (α - β)(\overline{\alpha} - \overline{\beta})$.

Isn't $|α + β|² = (|α + β|)(|α + β|)$? Why even consider using the conjugates?

Is there a proof for why $|α + β|² = (α + β)(\overline{\alpha} - \overline{\beta})$

[Complex Numbers Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX2Xg.png)

Comment: For any complex number $|x|^2 = x\overline{x}$.

Comment: Aside: The result you've been asked to prove can be interpreted as a statement about parallelograms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any(!) complex number $z = a+bi$, we have 
$$ z\bar z = (a+bi)(a-bi) = a^2 - (bi)^2 = a^2 + b^2 = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}^2 = |z|^2 $$
Hence, for $z = \alpha \pm \beta$:
$$ |\alpha \pm \beta|^2 = (\alpha \pm \beta)(\overline{\alpha \pm \beta}) = (\alpha \pm \beta)(\bar\alpha \pm \bar\beta) $$

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that $|z|^2 = z \cdot \overline z$, where $z$ is a complex number.  And this is easily shown by writing $z= x+iy$ and expanding.

\begin{align*}
  z\cdot \overline z &= (x+iy)(x-iy)\\
    &= x^2 -ixy +ixy -i^2 y^2\\
    &= x^2 - (-1)y^2\\
    &= x^2 + y^2
\end{align*}
And recall that
$$ |z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}. $$

Therefore $z\cdot \overline z = x^2+y^2 = |z|^2.$

> Why even consider using the conjugates?

Because that form of the expression can be helpful in proving other equalities.  A good example is the one in the image you linked.